# Trying to refresh information in one class to another in java

Tags: java, swing, file-io, java.util.scanner

I have a class called A and a class called T. When A clicks a button I want it to update something T. I am having issues doing this... any advice thanks.

Class A:

```
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("open.txt", true);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    out.write("\n" +number1);
    jLabel1.setText(number1);
    out.close();
    T t = new T();
    t.refresh();
```

refresh is the function I want to be called to update class T

T:

```
public void refresh() {
            File file = new File("open.txt");
    try {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

        if (sc.hasNext()) {
            jTextField2.setText(sc.next());

        } else {
            jTextField2.setText("Nothing to see here");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

That's the function I want it to call. It just doesn't update the text. I figure it's something related to how I use the text file. Any ideas thanks.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Make sure all GUI updates are made on the EDT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending to your file:

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("open.txt", true);
```

but reading the first value:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
if (sc.hasNext()) {
   jTextField2.setText(sc.next());
```

which won't ever change. I suspect that's why you're not seeing changes.

Do you need to write to that file ? Can't you just call your `refresh()` method (or an overloaded variant) with the data you've just written into the file ?

Comment: It's for if the file becomes blank and then something from the other class is added to make the file not blank to update the new class with the info.

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem? I basically want this so that if open.txt is empty and then I add something to it it updates it in the other class.

Comment: I added a button on class T to use the checkjobs method. It worked. But for some reason when I use it in class A it doesnt. Would it matter if the class T was created in another class?

Comment: I think you need to break this down. Does your refresh() method get called ? Does it read the right info from the file ? Can you set the text to a static string etc. etc.

Comment: I don't think it does. I have created T inside of another class called  B for example. The problem is A can't access B to access T...do you know what I mean? Like normally it would be t.refresh(); But because i'm inside another class that didn't create the t instance it's something like b.t.refresh(); How would I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Just try out the

```
TSO t = new TSO();
t.refresh();
```

above the

```
out.write("\n" +number1);
jLabel1.setText(number1);
out.close();
```

It May work but not confirmed...

Answer (score 0):

why don't you pass it as an argument

```
t.refresh(number1);
```

and then

```
public void refresh(String number1) {
 if(number1!=null){        
 jTextField2.setText(sc.next());
        } else {
            jTextField2.setText("Nothing to see here");
        }
    }
```

isn't it better